# How to control Windows runtime library variant (retail vs debug) independently of Boost build variant?

Tags: c++, windows, boost, build

When building a static library / application on Windows, there are 4 versions of the runtime library that can be used, via the flags `/MD`, `/MDd`, `/MT` and `/MTd` ([from official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=msvc-170)).

These 4 versions are mostly orthogonal from the build config (usually `Debug` vs `Release`) of the application, as long as all modules that are linked together use the same version of the Windows runtime.

With Boost, we have to use `b2`  to build the library. It provides the `runtime-link` parameter to control wether the dynamic or static version of the runtime will be used. But is there a parameter to control if the runtime library version will be **retail** or **debug**?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows runtime library variant **retail** or **debug** can be controlled via the b2 parameter `runtime-debugging`:

- `runtime-debugging=on` for the debug variant
- `runtime-debugging=off` for the retail variant

The parameter [is mentioned in the doc](https://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/builtins/features.html). Although the doc does not explicitly states that this parameter changes the runtime variant, we were able to confirm it does.